# Prevent font download from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webfonts

Is there a way to prevent people from just inspecting your website and downloading paid fonts via the Chrome Dev Tools window? Right now all I have to do is go to the Sources panel and Save link as / Open in a new tab, and I can download it.

Is there way to prevent this? Obfuscate or atleast make the process difficult?

Comment: What is the exact issue that you have with this? Licencing or server load? Something else? Right now, I can't see how either would be a _huge_ problem. If I'm wrong, then please explain.

Comment: Licensing and copyright. I’ve just launched a type foundry, and sell fonts on the website. But anyone can just inspect, and download the displayed fonts for free.

Answer (score 0):

1.
First, never create a physical link to the font itself. (Until a licence fee for that font has been paid for.)

2.
Use an image processor (i.e. ImageMagick) to create an *image* of the typeface sample(s)† and display that *image* as the sample on screen.

If you use these two steps above, there will not be an actual font file that they may download in an unwarranted manner.

3.
Allow only users those who have paid the licence access to the font `zip` file.

† Here is a working `php` sample of using ImageMagick to create an image of a typeface:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

// Create a new imagick object
$im = new Imagick();

// Create new image. This will be used as fill pattern
$im->newPseudoImage(50, 50, "gradient:red-black");

// Create imagickdraw object
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

// Set font/typeface
$draw->setFont("path/TheTypeface.ttf");

// Set font size to 72
$draw->setFontSize(72);

// Annotate some text
$draw->annotation(20, 50, "Hello World! This is my font sample!");

// Create a new canvas object and a white image
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(350, 70, "white");

// Draw the ImagickDraw on to the canvas
$canvas->drawImage($draw);

// Set the format to PNG
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

// Output the image
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;

?>
```

You will have to dicker with these settings, to get what you want. ImageMagick must be installed first, of course.

Note:

I'm going to be travelling internationally over the next few days which precludes Web access for me (programmer's heaven, right?). If you have any questions, please comment them here, and I will answer them when I land.

All the best. Sounds like a fun project.